# Which format specifier to use or how to achieve the below

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-formatting

I am making an calculator application for iOS. When I divide integers Eg: 10/4 I am getting 2.5 as result, Which is exactly as I expect because I don't want any extra 0's tailing my result(like 2.50000). I have used %g as format specifier. But this leads to another problem, Eg when I perform 10/3 I get 3.33333 NOW I am unhappy about this as theoretically I should get 3.3333333333 (recurring decimal, same goes when I do 22/7) which is what I want my calculator to display for such cases.

So my question is, which format specifier to use to get 10/4 = 2.5 and 10/3 = 3.3333333333 ? or how to achieve such behavior?

I have already referred [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) .

Comment: why downvote, it seems a genuine question and specific need to me. Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest using `NSNumberFormatter`, which not only lets you specify `minimumFractionDigits` and `minimumFractionDigits`, but also respects the user's localization preferences (e.g. in Germany, 2.5 is represented as "2,5").

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@(5.0 / 2.0), @(10.0 / 3.0)];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle; // if you don't want 1000's separator, perhaps use NSNumberFormatterNoStyle
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1;
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 5;

for (NSNumber *number in numbers) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:number]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the double result and then convert it into NSString using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f"]` or something like that - it depends on how many digits you want to show.

Then you can simply remove the last N zeros from your string. This will convert `@"2.500000"` into `@"2.5"` and `@"3.333333"` into `@"3.333333"`.

Comment: I am afraid, that is not correct solution in this case. If i use "%.6f" then when I divide 10/4 i will get "2.500000" WHERE as I want 2.5 because that is readable number to user of calculator. But when I do 10/3 I should get 3.3333333333.. because that is a recurring fraction and the user should know about it.